# Javascript: Shouldn't array.slice() return an array? What about Array.of()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

This is a Free Code Camp problem (which I solved myself--not too pretty, I know), but a couple array methods didn't work the way I thought they would (from reading the documentation on MDN). My questions are are about slice() and Array.of(): the questions are in the comments next to the pertinent code. Thanks!

Instructions: Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a two-dimensional array.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArray = [];

  for (i = 0; i < (arr.length) / size; i++) {
    var slicedArray = arr.slice(size * i, size + (size * i));
    console.log(typeof slicedArray); //This returns "object."
    Array.of(slicedArray); //But this returns "undefined"--even though my understanding (albeit shallow) is that *Array.of()* casts the object as an array. 
    newArray.push(slicedArray);
  }
  return newArray; // I tried to return *"This is the new array: "+ newArray*, but it seemed to case *newArray* as a string. Why? How to fix?
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
```

Comment: "This returns "undefined"; why?" --- unless it does not.

Comment: you've minimilaized the actual code too much, as the code you posted works as you expect it to

Comment: Put `console.log()` around the last line, you'll see it works fine.

Comment: Both `slice` and `Array.of` *do* return arrays, on which `typeof` will result in `"object"`. There's something else going on which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Btw, you'll most likely want `Math.ceil(arr.length / size)`

Comment: @zerkms Oh, right, I implicitly considered integer division. It does indeed work already, but `Math.ceil` would make sure that two integers are compared, and conveys the intent better.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for your observation; I went back and looked at my output, and I misspoke in my post. It does return "object".

Comment: @Bergi : There's nothing else going on in the code, nothing I haven't shown (I'm running it in repl.it--[link]https://repl.it/DjkT/8). It's just solving a little Free Code Camp puzzle. While typeof returns "object," isArray returns "undefined"--when I expect "true" (according to the MDN documentation), so I'm wondering how isArray works.

Comment: @Bergi: I added Math.ceil. But I thought it would have rounded to the closest lower integer anyway. What's the preference for using Math.ceil?

Comment: @NSchnupp Well the code at repl.it is not the one you've shown us in the question. And no, arrays don't have a boolean `isArray` property, that's why it's `undefined`. What you wanted would be  `console.log(Array.isArray(Array.of(…))) // true`